# Moved folder into submodule, now getting "Untracked files would be overwritten" message

Tags: git, git-submodules

I work on a team on a large repo. Recently we decided to move one of the folders into its own submodule

```
-- aaa
     -- .git
     --  bbb
     --  ccc
     --  www      # this folder is going into its own repo.
```

I followed the instructions to filter out the `www` folder into its own repo listed here: [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository).  I moved the `www` folder out of the `aaa` repo.

I removed the directory from the master branch by running these commands:

```
 $ cd aaa
 $ git checkout master
 $ git rm -rf www
 $ git commit -m "remove the www/ folder from the aaa repo."
```

So now on master, the tree looks like this:

```
 -- aaa
     -- .git
     --  bbb
     --  ccc
```

I'd like to add `www` as a submodule by running:

```
$ cd aaa
$ git checkout master
$ git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:kevinburke/www.git www
Cloning into 'www'...
remote: Counting objects: 717, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (392/392), done.
remote: Total 717 (delta 318), reused 711 (delta 317)
Receiving objects: 100% (717/717), 440.52 KiB | 58 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (318/318), done.
```

That works fine on master. However, any time I try to switch to another branch, I get the following error:

```
$ cd aaa
$ git checkout other-old-branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    www/1...
    www/2...
    www/3...
    www/4...
Aborting
```

How can I remove the `www` folder from all the branches in the `aaa` repo? There are about 100 branches, so doing this manually would be a hassle.

I'm not worried about keeping any outstanding changes that exist in `www` folders of older branches.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just use `git checkout -f` to swap branches, then remove them like you normally would and merge in master to get your submodule introduction.

Comment: Note that if you do a back-and-forth between branches, and the paths have overlapping file names, these files get deleted instead of being reset to the original content.

Comment: Can also happen in the reverse situation where the submodule was introduced on a branch, but not merged to master yet. In which case you just need to `git checkout -f`, without removing anything if you're moving to such a branch.

Comment: Better yet, use `git checkout -f --recurse-submodules`

Answer (score -1):

Since you have deleted the path only on working branch.
on all other branches the path is available.
So your submodule will cause conflict.